# Iphone,how to install new font to iphone by using objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, installation, new-operator

guys.
i have a pdf with a font that is not installed on iphone by default.
so,i want my application can install this font by using objective-c before my customer view this pdf.
any advice will be appreciate,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your applications .plist file, add a new property. In the list of properties, there should be something called "Fonts provided by application" - list any fonts that you have added to your app's resources folder. That should get you started :)

Comment: thanks,i'm new to iphone,i don't konw what to do after that,is there any tutorial or sample code? thanks

Comment: This tutorial explains it a lot clearer than I could: http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/  No prob, I'm new to iPhone dev too - I know this bit though because I got stuck on it just the other day ;)

Comment: thanks，jordan.unfortunately,it is not the same prob as mine.it used a css to control the html's font.but i use the uiwebview to render the pdf.this way can't change the pdf's font.may be i use a wrong way to view pdf.

Comment: Sorry can't help you there - I misread your question a bit. I guess, as a roundabout way, maybe you could convert the pdf into html? (google pdf to html, there are heaps of different ways to do it). That way you could use css to change the font. Not the most elegant solution ever though :(